# HTML : ¿Cómo hago para que mis párrafos estén uno al lado del otro y no uno abajo del otro?

Tags: html

Quiero hacer una prueba, y quiero que varios `<p>` esten uno al lado del otro

El codigo es este:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Grows, Garden!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <p id="slot0">~</p>
      <p id="slot1">~</p>
      <p id="slot2">~</p>
      <p id="slot3">~</p>
      <p id="slot4">~</p>
      <p id="slot5">~</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Y el resultado no es el que quiero, yo quiero que salga cada parrafo uno al lado de otro

Osea asi:

~ ~ ~ ~ ~

No aplique CSS, pero que tengo que hacer para que quede como quiero?

Comment: Nunca habia probado el span pero funciono, gracias! (pon una respuesta y te confirmo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias opciones para conseguir que los elementos se mantengan en una única línea.

Empezando por mantener tus elementos [`<p>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_p.asp), puedes usar CSS para convertirlos en elementos *"inline"*, es decir, que no añadan un salto de línea y se pinten uno al lado de otro.

```css
p { display: inline; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Grows, Garden!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <p id="slot0">~</p>
      <p id="slot1">~</p>
      <p id="slot2">~</p>
      <p id="slot3">~</p>
      <p id="slot4">~</p>
      <p id="slot5">~</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Personalmente, los elementos `<p>` son párrafos... y los párrafos siempre incluyen un salto de línea al final así que para casos así, prefiero usar otros elementos que ya son inline por si mismos:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Grows, Garden!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <span id="slot0">~</span>
      <span id="slot1">~</span>
      <span id="slot2">~</span>
      <span id="slot3">~</span>
      <span id="slot4">~</span>
      <span id="slot5">~</span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Como ves, utilizando [`<span>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp) en vez de `<p>` no necesitas ni añadir CSS, puesto que el comportamiento por defecto de este elemento es precisamente ese :)